# jQuery append doesn't always work

Tags: jquery, xml

I am using jQuery to parse XML. I got to the point where i get the values from it. The code is as follows:

```
$(xml).find('item').each(function(){
  var message = "<span>" + $(this).find('value').text() + "</span>";
  $(message).appendTo('#main');     
});
```

now, the problem is the following:

the code above works, but this code doesn't work:

```
$(xml).find('item').each(function(){
  var message = $(this).find('value').text();
  $(message).appendTo('#main');     
});
```

Comment: what do you mean by _it doesn't work_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the inverse of appendTo

```
$("#main").append(message);
```